# Magento 2 add custom layout in order email

Tags: magento2

I want to add a custom field in order email template.

I configured in **total.phtml** in **public_html/theme_name/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order**. It's working.

I tried to configure in

**items.phtml** in **public_html/theme_name/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order**. It had no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to overide the mail in front area. Never do this in vendor files.
Your module in vendor is `module-sales`, you can overide it by creating the module in your theme : 
 `app/design/<YourVendorName>/<your-theme>/Magento_Sales/`

Copy paste the directories/files you want to overide in this folder.